# Securing a Solr cloud?

Tags: security, solr, apache-zookeeper

I have to prove my SolrCloud is secure.

From my understanding of what I am reading I can secure the Solr instances talking to each other via basic authentication and SSL which is great, its secure, it works.

However, I can't see anything that will allow me to secure Zookeeper - or am I mistaken? Is there anything in an open Zookeeper that will allow a malicious user on my internal network to "hack" my SolrCloud, or is it the case that Zookeeper doesn't have anything that needs to be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding securing ZooKeeper, you may want to check [ZooKeeper access control using ACLs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.6/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_ZooKeeperAccessControl) link.

Comment: But as far as I can see, Zookeeper doesn't support HTTPs, if I have a packet sniffer, can't I sniff the Zookeeper packets?

Answer (score 0):

What we do at Measured Search for our customers who are using our Solr-as-a-Service platform, we allow them to restrict access to Zookeeper with IP filtering. They can either specify a specific IP address or a CIDR (range) that can have access to Zookeeper.

http://docs.measuredsearch.com/security/

That way, they can secure their Solr instances independently of Zookeeper.